# How to override div wrapper class of ckeditor Django?

Tags: django, ckeditor

Cant find a way to override ckeditor base wrapper div class.
By default it has html template like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZUJ.png

Is there a way to change class name "django-ckeditor-widget" to something else?
Was trying to do:

```
class PostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(), attrs={'class': 'MyCustomClass})
class Meta:
    model = Post
```

But this dosnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widget uses a simple template at "templates/ckeditor/widget.html" (see the [source](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/master/ckeditor/templates/ckeditor/widget.html)).  So create your own by that name in your app to override it (this requires your app appear before django-ckeditor in INSTALLED_APPS).